# Xcode 8.2 - Autolayout: xib run on different sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I get a problem using `xib`'s and Autolayout on Xcode 8.2. I have bind a Xib for each `viewController` which are then added on a storyboard.

My problem is to test different device sizes on my app. 
Everything is ok when I select the right "**View as: #device**". The view has the right size on the device for the selected `xib`.

For example. I can use an iPhone 6 and have a first `xib` well showed (`xib` as iPhone 6)  and then a second `xib` (`xib` as iPhone 6plus) which will be badly showed.

How to run the app and have the right "**View as...**" for each `xib` without having to reselect each one each time I want to test?